# Updating notification badge number base on the list iOS swift

Tags: ios, swift

Dear all iOS experts....  I'm currently implementing [Notification badge on segment Controls](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3cTwH.png)

Below are my codes

```
func addCounter(count: Int)->UIView {
    // Count > 0, show count
    if count > 0 {

        // Create label
        let fontSize: CGFloat = 10
        let label = UILabel()
        label.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: fontSize)
        label.textAlignment = .center
        label.textColor = .white
        label.backgroundColor = .red

        // Add count to label and size to fit
        label.text = "\(NSNumber(value: count))"
        label.sizeToFit()

        // Adjust frame to be square for single digits or elliptical for numbers > 9
        var frame: CGRect = label.frame
        frame.size.height += CGFloat(Int(0.4 * fontSize))
        frame.size.width = (count <= 9) ? frame.size.height : frame.size.width + CGFloat(Int(fontSize))
        label.frame = frame

        // Set radius and clip to bounds
        label.layer.cornerRadius = frame.size.height / 2.0
        label.clipsToBounds = true

        // Show label in accessory view and remove disclosure
        return label

    } else {
        return UIView()
    }
```

and my code under `ViewdidLoad()`

```
     self.badge1.addSubview(self.addCounter(count: 0))
```

as shown above `count:0` is the number of notification display under the badge. May I know is there any way for me to make the count as dynamic value based on the number of notification I received from the list?

Comment: Thank you sir @xivij for suggesting the edit

Answer (score 0):

Make a subclass of UIView named BadgeView with a property badgecount. It’s a UIView with a label inside, with the label hidden when the count is zero.

Create it, store it away, add it to your badge in viewDidLiad, and change its badgecount when needed.